# MySQL How would you do this question

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the problem:
I have a representation of a tree. let's abstract this to the fullest and say this is the tree: `(id, parent_id)`

the root is a row with `parent_id = null`

I'd like to create a table that lists all the descendants of all parents.

For example:

[image: A Chart Description of the tree]

The representation : `(1,null), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,3), (6,3)`

The result: `(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (3,5), (3,6)`

Comment: do you mean like: 1 has decendants: 2,3,4,5,6
and 3 has the decendants 5,6?

Comment: As shown in the example, he means what you describe ;-)

Comment: See this blog post: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: You want to convert your **Adjacency list** to a **Transitive closure of an adjacency list**. Read Quassnoi's links in this questions for other models: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486144/what-is-the-best-method-to-make-unlimited-sub-catgories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your representation is adjacency list, it's not possible to do this with one query. The fastest solution is to retrieve the whole data set and build what you need on the client side.

Check the nested set representation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here you can find a solution:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/